# ANTLR4 C# grammar and left recursion

Tags: c#, java, antlr4

I'm trying to parse C# code with ANTLR4 (from Java). So far, I was unable to find appropriate grammar, so I decided to write my own. I used this appendix [here](http://sdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) but I ran into a problem. The problem is that I have a lot of left-recursive rules. I tried to fix them by using ANTLRWorks (antlrworks-1.5) but I just keep getting exceptions. I was able to fix some of them manually, but not those like this one:

```
multiplicative_expression:
| unary_expression
| multiplicative_expression '*' unary_expression
| multiplicative_expression '/' unary_expression
| multiplicative_expression '%' unary_expression;
```

So is there anyone that could direct me to a proper grammar for ANTLR4 or to help me deal with left-recursion problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR 4 handles direct left recursion internally. The rule you posted above will work in ANTLR 4 without alteration.

Comment: Ok, thanks @280Z28 ,but when I try to generate parser and lexer from this grammar [here](http://pastebin.com/7EaMPAAh) that I found online, I get this error [here](http://pastebin.com/rLvLCpgq).

Answer (score 0):

A left-recursive rule is something of the form A -> Aa | b 
The forma way to solve this problem is by introducing a new nonterminal A' and rewrite the rule as

A -> bA'

A' -> Epsilon | aA' ( where Epsilon is the "Empty String" )

Since ANTLR is an LL parser generator, it can't stand the left-recursion.
However, the rigth-recursive rules are okay into ANTLR, so we can write the rules as:

```
multiplicative_expression:
| unary_expression
| unary_expression '*' multiplicative_expression 
| unary_expression '/' multiplicative_expression  
| unary_expression '%' multiplicative_expression  ;
```

Comment: ANTLR 4 supports direct left recursion. The `multiplicative_expression` rule works fine the way it was originally written.